# Access2010 pass-through oracle cte query

Tags: oracle, ms-access-2010

Given that

```
 SELECT identifier FROM referrals
```

..returns records.

Why do I get a 'Pass-through query with ReturnsRecords property set to True did not return any records' message when using the statement below?

```
WITH refs AS (SELECT identifier FROM referrals) SELECT identifier FROM refs
```

Any ideas? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my 'ODBC Connect Str' property from a file DSN to one in my registry and it worked. Does anyone know why?